# ESP01 won't boot when connected to the LED strip

Tags: esp8266

I have a weird bug behavior.
I have an ATX power supply, which powers a long WS2812B 5v strip, controlled by the [Esp 01](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000766948879.html) and the board...

Now the bug happens only when I connect the data pin to the strip. The ESP won't start after I restart the ATX PSU. And if it does it just crashes after some time...

Here is the SPOOKY part: when I start the esp WITHOUT the pin connected and plug it in after it starts it will keeep working for days... but sometimes it just decides it will go bananas... W T F! Any ideas why?????

I suspected voltage drops, but nope. I tried a battery, a second adapter and a USB power... none helped. Same behavior as soon as you connect the strip and hit restart/update, it goes bananas...

Comment: On ESPs there are some pins, that need to have a specific value during boot. As the ESP01 already has so few pins, you might have used one of them, so the connected strip might prevent the ESP from booting. I currently don't have the time, but you can google that yourself.

Comment: That is the tx pin. this is a standard led module which uses the standard GPIO2 pin. so it should not be possible that i got that pin. Any other ideas? i ordered an other esp so cross fingers it works.

Comment: it's probably pulling down gpio2, preventing a normal boot. watch the voltage on that pin during startup; if not vcc, bingo.

Comment: ye im suspecting that im missing the 500ohm resistor you should put on the data line. will update when i have it.

Answer (score 1):

I used a 470Ohm to connect GPIO2 and VCC. (to ensure HIGH during boot phase).
As suggested on : https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=77993

esp01 5v to 3.3shifter 470Ohm

[image: esp01 5v to 3.3shifter 470Ohm]

Regards,
Dom